# Azure kubernetes change pod disk type

Tags: azure, kubernetes

i need to change my azure kubernetes pod disk type from premium ssd to standard ssd, but the disk contains some data, can i directly change the type or need to migrate the data first?. thanks

disk type changed with old data still exists

Answer (score 0):

To change pod disk type from Premium to Standard, you can create new pod with standard disk type and then migrate/transfer the data. Finally, delete the old premium ssd pod.

See more details regarding Azure volume disk in :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage#persistent-volumes